# Mostrar la condición de una consulta como fila

Tags: sql

quisiera saber cómo se podrá hacer la siguiente consulta:

> Mostrar el número de empleados por intervalos de edad: <16, 16 a 25,
>   26 a 40, >40

Este es un ejemplo de la salida de la tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi consulta actual:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) 
FROM EMPLEADOS 
WHERE EDAD < 16 
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(ID) 
FROM EMPLEADOS 
WHERE EDAD > 15 AND EDAD < 26 
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(ID) 
FROM EMPLEADOS 
WHERE EDAD > 25 AND EDAD < 41 
UNION ALL 
SELECT COUNT(ID) 
FROM EMPLEADOS 
WHERE EDAD > 39
```

Comment: Bienvenido.Comparte la consulta que tienes, para poder ayudarte.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(ID)
FROM EMPLEADOS
WHERE EDAD < 16
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(ID) 
FROM EMPLEADOS
WHERE EDAD > 15 AND EDAD < 26
UNION
SELECT COUNT(ID)
FROM EMPLEADOS
WHERE EDAD > 25 AND EDAD < 41
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(ID)
FROM EMPLEADOS
WHERE EDAD > 39

Comment: Entiendo su empeño en usar UNION, pero aconsejo para la consulta aconsejo usar CASE para el Group By del count en una sola consulta. Ej: `SELECT 
CASE
WHEN EDAD BETWEEN 0 AND 15 THEN '<16'
WHEN EDAD BETWEEN 16 AND 25 THEN '16 a 25'
WHEN EDAD BETWEEN 26 AND 40 THEN '25 a 40'
WHEN EDAD > 40 THEN '>40'
ELSE
EDAD 
END Intervalo_edad
,COUNT(ID) Num_Empleados
FROM EMPLEADOS
GROUP BY CASE
WHEN EDAD BETWEEN 0 AND 15 THEN '<16'
WHEN EDAD BETWEEN 16 AND 25 THEN '16 a 25'
WHEN EDAD BETWEEN 26 AND 40 THEN '25 a 40'
WHEN EDAD > 40 THEN '>40'
ELSE
EDAD 
END`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando usas UNION, el motor de la base de datos implícitamente hace un `distinct`, por lo que puedes estar perdiendo filas. Para eso hay que usar `UNION ALL`.  Además, si no le añades un campo para saber qué significa cada número, sólo estarás confiando en el orden natural de la tabla.

Sería más sano hacer:

```
SELECT '< 16' as rango, COUNT(ID) FROM EMPLEADOS WHERE EDAD < 16 
  UNION ALL
SELECT '16 a 25' as rango, COUNT(ID) FROM EMPLEADOS WHERE EDAD >= 16 AND EDAD <= 25 
  UNION ALL 
SELECT '26 a 40' as rango, COUNT(ID) FROM EMPLEADOS WHERE EDAD >= 26 AND EDAD <= 40 
  UNION ALL 
SELECT '> 40' as rango, COUNT(ID) FROM EMPLEADOS WHERE EDAD > 40
```

Nótese que tu último rango estaba mal definido. Pusiste "mayor a 39" mientras que el rango anterior era "mayor a 25 y menor a 41" con lo cual las personas de 40 años aparecían en ambas filas.

Además, usé mayor o igual y menor o igual para los rangos intermedios. Es más fácil entender que los rangos incluyen el extremo, incluso en casos donde la edad debiera ser un número entero e intervalos discretos.

Answer (score 0):

Ya casi lo tienes.

```
SELECT '<16' INTERVALO_EDAD, COUNT(ID) NUM_EMPLEADOS
FROM EMPLEADOS 
WHERE EDAD < 16 
UNION 
SELECT '16 a 25' INTERVALO_EDAD, COUNT(ID) NUM_EMPLEADOS
FROM EMPLEADOS 
WHERE EDAD >= 16 AND EDAD <= 25
UNION 
SELECT '26 a 40' INTERVALO_EDAD, COUNT(ID) NUM_EMPLEADOS
FROM EMPLEADOS 
WHERE EDAD >= 26 AND EDAD <= 40
UNION
SELECT '>40' INTERVALO_EDAD, COUNT(ID) NUM_EMPLEADOS
FROM EMPLEADOS 
WHERE EDAD > 40
```

El uso de los alias INTERVALO_EDAD y NUM_EMPLEADOS, debe ser idéntico en todas las consultas para poder utilizar el operador `union`. Yo eliminaría el `union all`, ya que por el alias INTERVALO_EDAD, hace diferente cada registro y ya no hay problema que el union elimine numeros de empleados repetidos.

Toma en cuanto el uso de los operadores <= y >=. En el mismo enunciado te indican los rangos que debes tomar en cuenta.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, soy nuevo en sql y hay detalles que aún desconozco

Comment: Cierto, no va a perder filas por usar UNION, pero para el motor igual es más pesado ejecutarlo que usando UNION ALL